# Custom picker view with images

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uipickerview

I Learned how to use Picker views, singles and doubles. I would like to learn how to do a Picker view with images. Instead of numbers or words the scroll have different images to select one. Thanks. I think is using this code but it osent run me, I cant find the mistake. Thanks for your help.

```
 @synthesize picker, Array, image;



 - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
 {
      return 1;
 }


- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component;
{   
         return [self.Array count];

    }
 - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

 return [self.Array objectAtIndex:row];

 }

- (UIView *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:    (NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    NSString *img_src = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"6-12AM.png", row];

     UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:img_src]];

    return image;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I confused the function you need to implement in my initial answer. Sorry for that.

You need to implement the

**- (UIView *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view**

method of your UIPickerView delegate to return an UIImageView for a given row.

Reference page [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPickerViewDelegate)

for example (very dumb implementation without reusing views)

```
- (UIView *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
NSString * img_src = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d.png", row];

UIImageView * retval = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:img_src]] autorelease];

return retval;
}
```

assuming you have images named image_[num].png in your resources.

Comment: Sorry Peter Sarnoswski can you be more specific, thanks for your answer.

Comment: And how about the array? how do I make the array with all the images? I dosent get it sorry.

Comment: You must comment out the **titleForRow** method. And if you want to return images that are stored in an array, then just create it first :) and return apropriate objects.